# Clause linq with 2 parameter with operator OR don´t retrieve the values correctly

Tags: linq, where-clause, operator-keyword, clause

My problem is, I have a linq query with a where clause with 2 parameters,
the first parameters comes from the global filter, and the second comes from column filter.

When I enter the value in the global filter, and I don´t enter any value in column filter, (column will be string.empty) , I don´t have any value returned, but I should have.

Seem that every thing is ok, but I don´t see where is the mistake.

```
string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];
var column= Request.Form.GetValues("columns[0][search][value]").FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;

            var dataResut = data.Where(
                                p => 
                               p.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || p.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(column.ToLower())
                                ).ToList();
```

What I am missing here :(

Thanks in advance.

Jolynice

Comment: try adding parenthesis before you do OR like  

        data.Where(
                                p => 
                               (p.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())) || (p.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(column.ToLower()))
                                ).ToList();

Comment: Also syntactically var data = data wont work, may be here for easing it up you  might have used.. just FYI

Comment: Hello Bhadhiri, you are correct syntactically var data is not rigth, it was a bad copy paste, already updated. Thanks. I will try to add the parenthesis as you said.

Comment: with the parenthesis don´t work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
var dataResut = data.Where(
                            p =>
                           (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? false : p.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(column) ? false : p.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(column.ToLower()))
                            ).ToList();
```